# Flutter: MissingPluginException(No implemention found for method currentUser on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth) for iOS

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I don't know what it exception, id did't show in the past, but now it's showing!

this code on StartPage, it's checking if user signIn or not by cheking uid if null or not, if he signIn it convert to HomePage else to SignInPage.

I can't solve this problem with my self, I try more than one thing to solve this bug.
My app is broken because of this bug.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<User>(
        future: setUser(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data.uid != null) {
              return DefaultTabController(
                length: 2,
                child: Scaffold(
                  appBar: _buildAppBar(),
                  body: _buildTabView(context),
                ),
              );
            }
            return HomePage(
              user: snapshot.data,
            );
          }
          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  !snapshot.hasError
                      ? SpinKitCircle(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          size: 50,
                        )
                      : Icon(
                          Icons.warning,
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          size: 50,
                        ),
                  Text(
                    !snapshot.hasError
                        ? "يرجى الانتظار..."
                        : "مشكلة!" + "\n${snapshot.error.toString()}",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

setUser method:

```
Future<User> getUserData() async {
    User user;
    final FirebaseUser authUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    String uid = authUser.uid;
    DocumentSnapshot ds = await Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document('$uid').get();
    user = User(
      name: ds['name'],
      email: ds['email'],
      hospital: ds['hospital'],
      password: ds['password'],
      phoneNumber: ds['phone'],
      rank: ds['rank'],
      uid: uid,
    );
    return user;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried completely rebuilding the code instead of `Hot Reload`? Also try `Flutter Clean` to see if that helps. Alternatively, suggestions have been posted here which is similar to the issue you're facing: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14137

Comment: @Muhammad Hasan Alasady . Are you able to solve this? I am also facing same issue, while trying to run app on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36958

> solution: I copied the AppDelegate.m from the firebase app setup page. This works fine if there are no plugins but causes the MissingPluginException as soon as you start adding plugins. Correct code is:

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
@import UIKit;
@import Firebase;

@implementation AppDelegate

(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[FIRApp configure];
[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
return [super application:application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
//return YES;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but no luck may be because I have other plugin as well. And we can't be only with one plugin, There will be other plugin in app. We need a solution that works with other plugin as well.